# Docker Layer's On Disk Location

Tags: image, docker

I have been trying to figure out on-disk location of the layers included in the image but no luck.
I have looked at some of the similar post and suggested location /var/lib/docker/image/aufs/imagedb/content/sha256 and /var/lib/docker/image/aufs/layerdb/content/sha256 but I am still confused.

I am able to find layers associated with an image using "docker inspect " but not able to find on-disk location of image.

Using ubuntu 14.0 and running Docker version 1.11.2.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a quite old quesiton on this, hope it can provide some information for you [function of docker directory structure in /var/lib/docker/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016210/function-of-docker-directory-structure-in-var-lib-docker)

and my suggestion is that only if something bad happens, you don't need to care about the internal of the storage driver, docker will take care of it.